# List of creators + link

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want my user to create content in which he can select a creator (in a select list) of products displayed on his article. 
If he selects an existing creator during creation of the article, the publised article has to display the name of this creator + information about the creator (website + adress + maybe more). That means I have to enter this information into X fields for each creators.

If my user wants to add a new creator in this select list, he can do it directly when he creates his article. He enters the name of the creator + link to website + adress

My problem is that I don't know how to do it.

I've tried with that : 
*new taxonomy + 2 Link fields added fopr this taxonomy

But how can I enter the content of these fields linked to the taxonomy ? How can I allow my user to add content on new creators he wants to add ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and you are using Drupal 7, you need the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Entity connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module.

The [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module provides a field type with which you can reference other entities. When attached to your 'article' content type, your users can select an instance of the 'creator' content type.

To allow your users to dynamically create instances of the 'creator' content type, the [Entity connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect) module comes in handy. Two buttons will be provided next to the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field, one to create a new instance and the other to edit existing content.

Please let me know if you need more information/help.

Comment: Thx for the help.
But it doesn't let users add the content of the 2 fields.

For each new creator added, my user needs to enter a unique link + an unique adress. 

And by the way, Entity connect has no effect for me :/

Comment: Did you set the right permissions?

Comment: Yes, even simple users are supposed to see this button.

Comment: To see the Entity reference and Entity connect module in action, take a look at the tutorial of Code Karate: http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-entity-connect-module

Comment: I gave up but i've just noticed that you have to configure it to let users add/edit nodes ... Thanks for the help, I think it can do everything I want :)

Comment: Ok, good to hear! Permissions can be a bit troublesome sometimes. Good luck with your site.